# How to get a text from a JavaScript window using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have an application where on a click of a link, a JavaScript window with no URL is opened. I want to get a text written within this window after clicking the link.

- I've tried using `autoITx4java` without success.
- I've tried using windowhandles and alerts, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, if it is java script alert then you can use `Alert` functionality.

```
public static String getTextFromAlert(WebDriver driver){
    try {
        Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
        return alert.getText();
    }
    catch (NoAlertPresentException Ex) {
        // your custom code or assert condition for alert not present.
    }
    return null;
}
```

There are more methods for `Alert` to handle alerts in web window. `alert.accept();` accepts alert while `alert.dismiss();` dismiss the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code to handle javascript based pop up :

```
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();        

    // Capturing alert message.    
    String alertMessage= driver.switchTo().alert().getText();       

    // Displaying alert message     
    System.out.println(alertMessage);   
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    // Accepting alert      
    alert.accept();
```